# I2C slave not acknowledging consistently

Tags: arduino, i2c, embedded

I'm trying to communicate with a Cypress CapSense module, model CY8CMBR3106S. During initial testing, I used Cypress's CY3240-I2USB USB-I2C bridge, which works perfectly. I then moved to an Arduino for prototyping of my own application. However, I cannot seem to get the Arduino to communicate reliably with the CapSense controller. Using the I2C scanner sketch found [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner), the Arduino discovers the CapSense controller perhaps once out of every 40 or so attempts.

In an attempt to debug this, I scoped the bus using both the Cypress USB-I2C bridge and the Arduino. I found that the controller always gives an ACK with the Cypress bridge, and almost never generates an ACK with the Arduino. However, other than the different voltages and clock rates (which I have played around with to no avail), I cannot seem to find any major differences between the frames sent from the two different sources which would explain the inconsistent ACKs.

At this point, I am at something of a loss--any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here are a few scope captures--note that channels 1 and 2 are SCL and SDA, respectively.

Successful communication using Cypress bridge (note ACK after 8th clock pulse)
[image]

Failed communication using Arduino (note lack of ACK)
[image]

Very rare successful communication using Arduino
[image]

Comment: Judging by the traces, the Cypress I2C bridge has got stiffer pull-up resistors on the I2C bus.

Comment: What voltage is the sensor running at? The datasheet says the max voltage on an IO pin is Vdd+0.5. In the first trace the comms are done at 3.3V, in the second case it is done at 5V. Is that in spec?

Comment: Tom--I don't think it's the frequency or voltage; I've tried a 3.3V Arduino and higher I2C clock rates with no change. Nick, the Cypress bridges has 7.5K pull-ups, and the Arduino is currently set up with 10Ks. I can try swapping them out for 7.5Ks and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tom--in the first capture with the Cypress bridge, VDD and comms are both at 3.3V. In the latter captures with the Arduino, VDD and comms are both at 5V (although I've also tried a 3.3V Arduino, as mentioned above).

Comment: I went ahead and tried the Arduino with 6.8K pull-ups and a higher clock rate--no dice.

Comment: http://imgur.com/PS4lB6z

Comment: Although, as you can see from the capture, changing the pull-ups doesn't seem to have affected the rise/fall characteristics much.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the signal. Does the chip still work reliably with the USB to I2C adapter?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it with the bridge again and it is still working fine.

Comment: Well, the problem appears to be solved, although I am unsure as to why... I previously had a 5 second delay between communication attempts. Reducing this delay to less than about 400 ms seems to fix the issue--the first frame fails, but all subsequent frames are met with an ACK.  Setting the delay to around 500 ms or above brings the problem back. This explains the issue, since the Cypress bridge test software sends frames continuously at high frequency. However, I'm not sure why the CapSense controller would be sensitive to the inter-frame delay... some kind of idiosyncrasy with the I2C HW?

Comment: In fact, as far as I can tell from page 26 of the [datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/file/46236/download), there must be at least 1.3 microseconds of bus-free time between frames, but there should be no "maximum" amount of bus-free time.

Comment: See page 32, item 3, it mentions a 340ms maximum delay. Relevant?

Comment: Roger--great catch. I think the issue actually stems from both that and item 2 on the same page: the device gives a NACK for the first I2C transaction after waking into the active state. Since my transactions were spaced further apart than the timeout from the active state to the low-power state, every transaction was the first transaction in the active state, meaning that I would never see an ACK. This also explains why the first frame still fails, as I mentioned above. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, does anyone know what causes that little "notch" that consistently appears on the SCL line immediately prior to the start of the frame?

Comment: Induced voltage from SDA line?

Comment: Yeah, looks like capacitive coupling

Comment: I know you've solved the problem, but when you get a chance you should post and accept your own detailed answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, the solution in this case was to increase the frequency of the I2C transmissions.

Per the datasheet, the Cypress CapSense controller gives a NACK on the first I2C transaction after waking into the active state. As [@Roger Rowland](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/52562/roger-rowland) noted, after around 340 ms of inactivity on the bus, the controller goes into a low-power state. Since my transmissions were spaced further apart than this timeout, each transmission would wake the device from the low-power state into the active state and receive a NACK. This problem is resolved by increasing the frequency of the transmissions to less than the timeout value, or by repeating a given transmission back-to-back until an ACK is received.